# Timer countdown even when program is not running QML

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qml

I am trying to have a 24 hour countdown on my user interface in a QML/Qt project. The time should update every second like 23:59:59 then 23:59:58. Additionally, I need the time to continue going down even when the application is not open. So if the time is 23:59:59 when I close the app, if I open it two hours later it should continue counting down from 21:59:59. If the timer had timed out when the app isn't running, it needs to reset to 24 and continue. Does anyone know how I could do this, either QML or connected c++? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Save the start time somewhere and then compare against current time.

Comment: @JarMan QTime only counts for the pure time at the moment, how do I know if it has already been more than 24 hours and it has cycled back again.

Comment: Use a QDateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store *somewhere* timer's end time according to system clock or equivalent information. So at each moment you can tell timer's value by taking difference between system clock's `now()` and timer's end.

Just use `std::this_thread::sleep_until` to wait to the exact moment you need to update the time for the next second. Don't use `sleep_for(1s)` as this way you'll accumulate inaccuracies.

Note: system clock has an issue that it can be adjusted. I don't fully know of a way around it - say your application turned off then how to tell how much time passed if system clock was adjusted? You can deal with clock adjustment during application run by using `sleep_until` with `steady_clock`. In C++ 20 they introduce `utc_clock` perhaps you can access that somehow which should solve the issue with daylight saving time adjustments. I don't think that it is theoretical possible to deal with all types of clock adjustments unless you have access to GPS clock.